# Output only part of array based on initial char

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array `$myArr['words']` that contains data in the following format:

```
Array (
[above-the-fold] => Array
  (
    [term] => Above the fold
    [desc] => The region of a Web ...
  )

[active-voice] => Array
  (
    [term] => Active voice
    [desc] => Makes subjects do ...
  )

[backlinks] => Array
  (
    [term] => Backlinks
    [desc] => Used on content ....
  )
)
```

I output the content like this:

```
foreach($myArr['words'] as $k => $v) {
  echo '
  <a href="#'.$k.'">
    '.$v['term'].'
  </a>';
}
```

How do I add a constraint to output only the values $k starts with particular character. For example:

```
$ltr = 'a';
```

Comment: Provide an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$test = ['abc'=>'1', 'def'=>'2', 'deh'=>'3'];

foreach($test as $k => $v){
    if($k[0] == 'd') {
        echo $v . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/e7I8m

Comment: Note if the key above starts with an uppercase, it will be ignored. So here is an [example using **strcasecmp**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15cf3a83fbabbb910fd4ca9e3486f73d017c069f).

Answer (score 1):

You can use also a more flexible way: match by **regular expression**:

```
<?php

$myArr = [
    'zzzz' => [
        'term' => 'zuzuzu',
        'desc' => 'zazaza ...'
    ],
    'above-the-fold' => [
        'term' => 'Above the fold',
        'desc' => 'The region of a Web ...'
    ],
    'active-voice' => [
        'term' => 'Active voice',
        'desc' => 'Makes subjects do ...'
    ],
    'backlinks' => [
        'term' => 'Backlinks',
        'desc' => 'Used on content ....'
    ]
];

$reg = "/^a/";   // Key starts with "a" 

foreach (preg_grep($reg, array_keys($myArr)) as $k => $v)
    echo "<a href=\"#$v\" title=\"{$myArr[$v]['desc']}\">{$myArr[$v]['term']}</a>\n";
```

echoes:

```
<a href="#above-the-fold" title="The region of a Web ...">Above the fold</a>
<a href="#active-voice" title="Makes subjects do ...">Active voice</a>
```

[Live example on Online PHP](https://3v4l.org/RLFWO)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

You can check the key for position 0:

```
if(strpos($k, 'a') === 0) {
    //echo
}

//or

if($k[0] === 'a') {
    //echo
}
```

Or filter the array and `foreach` over the `$result`:

```
$result = array_filter($myArr['words'],
                       function($v) { return $v[0] === 'a'; },
                       ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the first letter of the string (like accessing `array` indexes) and see if it is your desired character.

Here's an example to show all the terms starting with `a` or `A` :

```
$arr = [
    'above-the-fold' => [
        'term' => 'Above the fold',
        'desc' => 'The region of a Web ...'
    ],
    'active-voice' => [
        'term' => 'Above the fold',
        'desc' => 'The region of a Web ...'
    ],
    'backlinks' => [
        'term' => 'Above the fold',
        'desc' => 'The region of a Web ...'
    ]
];

foreach($arr as $k => $v) echo ($v['term'][0] != 'a' && $v['term'][0] != 'A') ?: $v['term'];
```

Here's a [live](https://3v4l.org/IdoBE) demo.